# Support HTTP and HTTPS in a SOAP service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, soap

I imported a SOAP service by using "Add -> Service reference" in Visual Studio. This generates a lot code that helps for consuming the service.

The SOAP has to call different endpoints for every different customer base using the application. Some are endpoints are in plain HTTP, and others are HTTPS. (All on internal network so HTTP is not a big deal). Every HTTP endpoint works fine, every HTTPS endpoint works, but the application wont support both.

This configuration supports HTTPS:

```
        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.ServiceV201209Soap))
            {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            return result;
            }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }
```

Removing the "Security.Mode" line will support HTTP.

I have trouble switching between the modes. The best that I could do was check wether the end point was HTTP or HTTPS, and change the binding configuration during runtime. But this made it work only on the second SOAP call after switching endpoints. That is horrible so I scrapped that.

Is there a simple configuration that definitely supports both?

Comment: Since Removing the "Security.Mode" line will support HTTP.You could add a judgment. Bool isHtpps

Comment: Is there any update in this issue?